# Pass Values between asp.net webpages while cannot modify values

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-webpages

I am using this and I know it is not good:

```
protected string GetCompanyUrl (object companyNum, object balance)
    {
        return "./companyDetails.aspx?companyId=" + companyNum.ToString() + "&balance=" + balance.ToString(); 
    }
```

But if I change the balance value in the url, the page will show the company info with wrong balance values.

So I tried to use `Session["balance"]=balance.ToString();`
but, as balance is from gridview and has many rows, it has many values, and it does not keep track of the values corresponding to the companyId.

Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Passing the **CompanyId** in query string is acceptable approach, but **Balance** is kind of weird. The problem is **Balance** can be 123.45, and **.** (dot) might cause the problem.

Ideally, you just want to pass **CompanyId** in QueryString, and retrieve that balance of the company (from database) in next page.

Comment: Having a dot in a query parameter shouldn't be a problem, but if it is, you can always url escape it.

Comment: @Servy: hi, you are right, the dot was not a problem. But I wanna debate that, although the 2 questions are from solving one problem, they are solving in different aspects. And the title does reflects asking for solution on different ways of solving different problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go for this

```
protected string GetCompanyUrl (object companyNum)
{
        return string.Format("~/companyDetails.aspx?companyId={0}",
        companyNum.ToString());
}
```

On the company details page, pick the comapny num and query with your database for required value. If you need your users unable to figure out the exact company number, you can simply use Base64 encoding and decoding.